# How to change BrowserRouter and HashRouter depend on variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
if(document.location.protocol != "http:" && document.location.protocol != "https:"){
  window.render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route ... />
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  }
} else {
  window.render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route...
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  }
}
```

How I can refactor this code? For example I need smth like below. Because routes are the same in Browser, Hash. I need to change only kind of router depend on state of variable

```
document.location.protocol ? <HashRouter/> : <BrowserRouter/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional rendering/just creating a new component is your friend here.

```
const CommonComponent = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route ... />
  </Switch>
)

window.render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(     
    <Provider store={store}>
      {(document.location.protocol != "http:" && document.location.protocol != "https:") ? (
        <HashRouter history={history}>
          <CommonComponent />
        </HashRouter>
      ) : (
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
          <CommonComponent />
        </BrowserRouter>
      )}
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
```

Comment: it is not solve a problem, code still duplicated

Comment: @Stasoz I guess you needed the bit inside the router factored out? I've edited my answer.